# How to write unit tests for a function using dbus to get information from Spotify?

Tags: python, linux, unit-testing, dbus

I have this function

```
def get_info_linux():
    import dbus

    session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    spotify_bus = session_bus.get_object("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify",
                                         "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2")
    spotify_properties = dbus.Interface(spotify_bus,
                                        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
    metadata = spotify_properties.Get("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player", "Metadata")
    track = str(metadata['xesam:title'])
    artist = str(metadata['xesam:artist'][0])
    return artist, track
```

This takes information from spotify using dbus. How do I write unit tests for it?

Answer (score 2):

The most common approach to testing this kind of D-Bus service client is to run it against a fake D-Bus session bus, which has a mock implementation of the Spotify service running on it (controlled by your test code).

You can use [`GTestDBus`](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/class.TestDBus.html) to create the mock session bus, then use the normal GDBus APIs to expose a D-Bus object on it. Create a `Gio.DBusConnection` connected to the address returned by [`g_test_dbus_get_bus_address()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/method.TestDBus.get_bus_address.html), then expose an object on it at D-Bus object path `/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2`, implementing at least the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` properties, and returning mock data for the properties that your code-under-test queries.

Your code-under-test should use the mock session bus when run under a test harness because `GTestDBus` overrides the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable, which GIO uses (by default) to look up the address of the real session bus.

Answer (score -1):

Directly writing unit tests for something that has dependencies on the network is not a good idea and will also not ensure that your tests have the same behavior all the time.

But you can circumvent this adding an abstract interfere. This interface can be implemented by your current approach which is used in your code and you can implement a stub which you use in your tests. This returns whatever you like.

Comment: Bit of a generic answer.

Comment: Dbus does not really have anything to do with the network, it is local to the current system.